# Something strange about indexPath.row in swift

Tags: swift

I try to test tableview in swift.

and I write this code as below

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChecklistItem") as UITableViewCell
   let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as UILabel

    for var i = 0; i < 100 ; i++ {
        label.text = "I am in indexPath.row= \(indexPath.row)"
        println("I am in indexPath.row= \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

I want to display the sentence "I am in indexPath.row= i " in 100 rows and I got the result as I expected in simulator

but when I look in debug area, I see something very strange because inside the loop, I assign the label and I also `println()` the indexPath.row. but `println()` in debug area it prints "I am in indexPath.row=0" and "I am in indexPath.row=0"  and "I am in indexPath.row=0"  like this.

please check the photo in this link. because I don't have enough reputation to post image.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ed2plgsb520lgq/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-21%20at%205.14.37%20PM.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvguwz51nmfzwgu/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-21%20at%205.14.51%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: You are doing 100 `println` and setting of the label _for every row._ You don't see the redundant setting of the labels in the UI, but you see all of those `println` statements. Eliminate that `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What purpose is the `for` loop serving? It is the reason you are seeing the duplicate prints. `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath`takes care of looping through the cells so you don't have to worry about looping at all.

Comment: what I don't understand is: indexpath.row show from 1 to 100 in label in simulator but it shows the redundant only 0 0 0 0 0 ..... then 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 so on in debug area. why?

Comment: Because you aren't adding more rows inside of `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` with your for loop. All your for loop is doing is a) resetting a the label to be the same 100x and b) log to console each row 100x. That is why you see the redundant logs in your console area and not in the UI of your app. If you want to add more rows to your table view, you would do that in the datasource method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: thank you so much. now i think that i understand about this :)